# How to set a PropertyActionListener in a <p:datatable>

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I use PrimeFaces , i want to set an action listner on the selected row to show one of his column in a dialog.

my datatable look like this:

```
<p:dataTable var="ligne" value="#{detailGrilleBean.lignes}">  
            <p:column headerText="Question">  
                <h:outputText value="#{ligne.questionBs}" />  
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Note">                     
                <p:rating value="#{ligne.reponse}" readonly="true" />  
            </p:column>  
            <p:column headerText="Justification">  
                <p:commandLink  oncomplete="nDialog.show();" title="View Detail" >  
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{ligne}"   
                       target="#{detailGrilleBean.selectligne}" />
                    <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="margin:0 auto;" "/>  
                </p:commandLink> 
            </p:column>  
        </p:dataTable>
```

The dialog :

```
       <p:dialog   hideEffect="fade" width="600" height="100" id="dialogdesc"  widgetVar="nDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" closable="true" appendToBody="true">  
            <p:outputPanel id="nDetail" style="text-align:center;">  
                <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                    <h:outputText id="type" value="#{detailGrilleBean.selectligne.justification}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </p:outputPanel>  
        </p:dialog>
```

The Backingbean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DetailGrilleBean implements Serializable {

Grille grille;
List<Lignegrille> lignes;
Lignegrille selectligne;
//Getters & Setters
```

When running the dilog, it just don't show anything.
I tried to put some logging in the setter and getter of the selectedligne property, but what i get is only the output log last element of the lignes;

PS: I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5 / Tomcat EE 1.6

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the dialog content. I.e. set `update=":nDetail"` (id depends on where the dialog is placed) on the `commandButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Now you not call any action listner, you only put parameter. In your case you have two option:
1. Make your dataTable as selectable dataTable, example you find on primefaces home page.
2. Prepare your commandLink like this(of cource dataTable and dialog must be in form):

```
<p:commandLink oncomplete="nDialog.show();" 
               title="View Detail"
               actionListener="#{detailGrilleBean.setSelectligne(ligne)}"
               process="@this"
               update="nDetail"/>
```